# PHP Getting certain parts of a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following tire sizes in my database, all formatted in different ways.  Here are a few examples:

```
225/50R17
255/45R18/XL
P155/80R13
```

What I need is to separate them in 3 parts, and JUST the numbers.

So the first one should be:  **225 / 50 / 17**  all separate variables.
Second one should be: **255 / 45 / 18** and ignore the XL.  And the third one obviously should be **155 / 80 / 13**

Does anyone know how I can write a function or whatever needs to be done to just grab those numbers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function:

```
$str = '255/45R18/XL';
$chars = preg_split('/[^\d]/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($chars);
```

This results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 255
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 18
)
```

You'll probably want to have the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag in there, otherwise you'll end up with empty elements in your array.

You're essentially splitting on characters that aren't digits, so `preg_split()` seems like the natural choice.

Comment: Is there a way to only show unique numbers?  If I am echoing $chars[0] and theres 20 of them that have the same number, how do I only show one?

Comment: @Drew: That's really a separate question, but once you have your arrays of numbers, you would just loop through them and check `$chars[0]`. If you've seen it before, just skip, otherwise print it and add it to a list of numbers you've seen before.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this:

```
    

$ar = array(
  '225/50R17',
  '255/45R18/XL',
  'P155/80R13'
);

foreach ($ar as $a) {
    if (preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $a, $match)) {
        print "match=[". print_r($match[0], true) . "]\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Which produces output like this:

match=[Array
(
    [0] => 225
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 17
)
]
match=[Array
(
    [0] => 255
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 18
)
]
match=[Array
(
    [0] => 155
    [1] => 80
    [2] => 13
)
]

Comment: So I write my huge, long winded answer, go and test that regex on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=\d%2B&input=225%2F50R17%0A255%2F45R18%2FXL%0AP155%2F80R13%0A) and it just works! +1 for a good answer.

Comment: @JamWaffles nice link, although I genrally prefer to write self contained scripts since I find them easier to share, put under source control, etc. If you want to get hardcode are see an animated Finite State Automaton representation of your regex, [check this out](http://osteele.com/tools/reanimator/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers will always have at least 2 digits a regular expression like this will work:

```
(\d{2,})\/(\d{2,}).*?(\d{2,})
```

**Demo:** http://rubular.com/r/l3IDSzU7oH

Comment: It builds a graphical representation of a Finite State Automaton for your regex and animates the operation of the FSA as it chews on a text string. Which is pretty awesome, if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: @peter sounds cool but i always get red (no match), will give it a better check later..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to do this:

```
$text = "255/45R18/XL";

$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/(\d+)/", $text, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

After preg_match_all $matches will look like:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "255/45R18/XL"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "255"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "45"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "18"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3cb0f

```
<?php
$string = '225/50R17';
$filtered = preg_replace('~[a-z]+~i', '/', $string);
$exploded = explode('/', $filtered);
foreach($exploded as $one){
    if (!empty($one)){
       echo "<b> ".$one."</b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting domain. What else do you use it for?

Comment: @Peter: currently for nothing, but it was interesting one so I have taken it

Answer (score 0):

Providing it's always an R that splits numbers, this code should work (untested):

```
$string = // Get the current row from the database

// Replace all occurences of `R` with a `/`
str_replace("R", "/", $string);

// Remove any letters
$string = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]/i", "");

// Split string into an array
$numbers = explode("/", $string);

// Get rid of any empty elements
foreach($numbers as $index => $value)
{
    if(empty($value))
    {
        unset($numbers[$value]);
    }
}
```

There are probably better ways to do it, but this should work for most if not all cases.

Do bear in mind that this is only for one row and should be put in your MySQL `while()` loop or whatever. You can then append `$numbers` to an array holding all tyre sizes or whatever you'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it without regexp just in case your strings aren't that predictable

```
function remove_crap ($crapString) {
    //build an alphabet array
    for ($character = 65; $character < 91; $character++) {
        $potentialCrap[] = chr($character);
    }
    //throw in slash or whatever other crap there might be with the numbers
    $potentialCrap[] = "/";
    //strip out all potential crap
    $newString = str_replace($potentialCrap, '', $crapString);
    //readd the slashes where they go, totally better ways to do this but i'm tired and want to go home
    $finalString =  $newString[0].$newString[1].$newString[2]."/".$newString[3].$newString[4]."/".$newString[5].$newString[6];
    return $finalString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<?php
$s = "145/80R13";
$x = preg_split('/\/|[a-z]|[A-Z]|-| /', $s);
print_r($x);
```

?>